# Jquery zoom plugin doesn't aim and zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming, jqzoom

We are using jqzoom on one of our e-shops and I can't figure out, why zoom is not working.

Using jquery-1.8.3, jqzoom-core.js (jQzoom Evolution Library v2.3). Everything works, but picture is not zoomed and centered as you can see on screens below.

There is jquery code:

```
        $('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
        zoomType: 'standard',
        preloadImages: true,
        lens:true,
        alwaysOn:false,
        zoomWidth: 490,
        zoomHeight: 480,
        xOffset:70,
        yOffset:0,
        title: false,
    });
```

Screens here (you can see that image is not zoomed => centered): [image][image]

Any idea, where to start? What can I check? What can I try to change?